# List column not showing in search crawled properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have a SharePoint online team site with a custom list having few items. This list has a single selection lookup column with name "IssueType". I want to use this field as a refiner in my search for items on this list. There is an index on IssueType column and search is enabled on list. I reindexed the list few times yesterday (> 24 hours ago). Still the crawled property for this IssueType column is not coming up in the search schema. However, for another lookup column crawled property is coming up.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue and troubleshoot missing crawled properties. Also, do refiners work for multi-lookup columns?

Comment: Just to clarify, the column you're attempting to use to end up with a crawled property does have data in it, doesn't it? If the column doesn't have any data in it, a crawled property won't be generated.

Comment: Yes, have data in List items for this column(IssueType column)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But, SharePoint creates a managed property for custom site columns(not sure about custom list columns).Also you need to have the data in the column(which you are having already) and do the full crawl on site.

Answer (score 1):

Check Sp148979, MS has an issue crawling properties right now

Comment: Still not fixed on my side. Are new crawled properties created for you?

Comment: Yes, I haven't had any issues with that lately

Answer (score 1):

I have done a test in my SharePoint Online, i create single selection lookup column with name "IssueType" in a list, set value for the column.

It is showing in search crawled properties. Then i created managed property which map to the crawled property.

For your issue, try to recreated the look up column.

Yes, refiners work for multi-lookup columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue - https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/35566249-creation-of-crawled-properties

It is expected to be fixed by Oct 19,2018 at latest  by MS.
The RCA is - A code issue caused the infrastructure responsible for search and indexing to become degraded.

Please mark as answer if you find it answers your query.